# How to Display Button in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a xml page and I want to Display in RecyclerView and in xml have I have two button, but util buttons are in xml, program cant run and when I remove the buttons The problem is solve.

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_txt_StudentList_StudentName"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Absent"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:text="غیبت"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorToolbar"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_txt_StudentList_StudentName"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_txt_StudentList_StudentName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Delay"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="تاخیر"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorToolbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Absent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Absent"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Absent"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

logcat:

```
Process: com.example.user.classmanager, PID: 10078
                                                                           android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                               at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                               at com.example.user.classmanager.RecyclerViewAdapter_StudentList.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter_StudentList.java:80)
```

Comment: what's the problem? what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem :

i resolved my problem . the problem was color background for button.

======> android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

Solution :

Design Special Layout For Button

Answer (score 0):

your

> android:layout_below

in first button is missing. try to add

> android:layout_below or
>
> android:layout_top or
>
> android:layout_right or
>
> android:layout_left.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use left and right,and also end and start at the same time.
you have to use left and right or start and end separately.
When your app language is farsi ,you would better to use 
android:layoutDirection="rtl" that help you keep your design

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layoutDirection="rtl">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_txt_StudentList_StudentName"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Absent"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_txt_StudentList_StudentName"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:text="غیبت"
    android:textColor="@color/colorToolbar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Delay"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Absent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_btn_StudentList_Absent"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:text="تاخیر"
    android:textColor="@color/colorToolbar" />
```

Comment: i do it but Does not work , dadash age tonesti id telegram midi barat kamel tozih bedam

Comment: @NimaKhalili id:@Alireza_aslami